Lorenz gauge implies a magnetic flux wave?
The electric field $\mathbf{E}$ and magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ can be written in terms of the electric scalar potential $\phi$ and magnetic vector potential $\mathbf{A}$ as:
$$\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\phi-\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t},\tag{1}$$
$$\mathbf{B}=\nabla \times \mathbf{A}.\tag{2}$$
There is gauge freedom in the definitions of $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ such that we can make the following change without affecting $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$:
$$\mathbf{A} \rightarrow \mathbf{A} + \nabla \psi,\tag{3}$$
$$\phi \rightarrow \phi-\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}.\tag{4}$$
The Lorenz gauge which maintains Lorentz invariance is given by
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=0.\tag{5}$$
Maxwell's equations become the following wave equations for the electromagnetic potentials $\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$:
$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\phi=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0},\tag{6}$$
$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\mathbf{A}}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\mathbf{A}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}.\tag{7}$$
Now if we substitute Eqn.$(3)$ and Eqn.$(4)$ into Eqn.$(5)$ we find a scalar wave equation for $\psi$ given by
$$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\psi=0.\tag{8}$$
Does Eqn.$(8)$ describe a magnetic flux $\psi$ wave travelling at the speed of light?

I do not understand your question. The flux across a surface $\mathcal F$ is $\Phi = \int\int_{\mathcal F} \mathbf B \cdot d\mathbf f =\oint_{\partial \mathcal F} \mathbf A d\ell,$ as such the closed contour integral is then independent of $\psi$. In other words, the gauge has no effect on the flux.

The Lorentz gauge is not enough to completely fix the gauge, unlike the Coulomb gauge. (8) therefore just represents a remaining unfixed gauge degree of freedom. In Fourier space, the Lorentz gauge amounts to killing the time like component of the modes, but when the 4-wave vector is on shell, this is ambiguous hence the remaining gauge freedom. (8) therefore does not represent any physical wave, and is an artifact of the redundancy of gauge invariance. This is a simplified analogue of why it took so long for gravitational waves in GR to be taken seriously. You could obtain similar looking waves, but then realise that they were just unphysical waves in the gauge freedom.
